# using decorators to persist python objects

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Code that I got from below link, can persist data to the disk.

http://tohyongcheng.github.io/python/2016/06/07/persisting-a-cache-in-python-to-disk.html

I tried it but the file does not get generated.

```
import atexit
import pickle
# or import cPickle as pickle

def persist_cache_to_disk(filename):
    def decorator(original_func):
        try:
            cache = pickle.load(open(filename, 'r'))
        except (IOError, ValueError):
            cache = {}

        atexit.register(lambda: pickle.dump(cache, open(filename, "w")))

        def new_func(*args):
            if tuple(args) not in cache:
                cache[tuple(args)] = original_func(*args)
            return cache[args]

        return new_func

    return decorator
```

I tried to use this code as per the example...

```
@persist_cache_to_disk('users.p')
def get_all_users():
    x = 'some user'
    return x
```

Update:

This is working at python command prompt, but does not work in ipython notebook.

Comment: I tried it and the file generated OK. Have you looked in the directory where the script is in addition to the current directory?

Comment: Yes. The file gets generated correctly while using python prompt. But I am using ipython notebook and I do not see the pickle file.

Comment: A 0 byte file is generated when I restart kernel. How do I stop script execution without interruption within notebook environment?

Comment: Persistent objects are exactly what the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module is for. Once the 'shelf' is created, you can call its `sync()` method at any time to write the data to disk. Also be aware that an `atexit()` handler will not be called in all process termination cases. The code also doesn't seem to handle the cached data becoming 'stale'. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Note that this will fail for arguments including unhashable objects (such as dictionaries or lists).

Answer (score 11):

The problem is the example employs `atexit` which runs the dump routine only when python exits.  This modified version will dump each time the cache is updated:

```
import atexit
import functools
import pickle
# or import cPickle as pickle

def persist_cache_to_disk(filename):
    def decorator(original_func):
        try:
            cache = pickle.load(open(filename, 'r'))
        except (IOError, ValueError):
            cache = {}

        # Your python script has to exit in order to run this line!
        # atexit.register(lambda: pickle.dump(cache, open(filename, "w")))
        #
        # Let's make a function and call it periodically:
        #
        def save_data():                                                        
            pickle.dump(cache, open(filename, "w"))  

        # You should wrap your func
        @functools.wraps(original_func)
        def new_func(*args):
            if tuple(args) not in cache:
                cache[tuple(args)] = original_func(*args)
                # Instead, dump your pickled data after
                # every call where the cache is changed.
                # This can be expensive!
                save_data()
            return cache[args]

        return new_func

    return decorator


@persist_cache_to_disk('users.p')
def get_all_users():
    x = 'some user'
    return x

get_all_users()
```

If you wanted to throttle the saving, you could modify `save_data()` to only save, say, when the `len(cache.keys())` is a multiple of 100.

I also added `functools.wraps` to your decorator.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html):

> Without the use of this decorator factory, the name of the example function would have been 'wrapper', and the docstring of the original example() would have been lost.

Answer (score 7):

The best solution depends on the use case. There is no general way to solve all problems at once.

### Caching data

If you want to speed up function calls, you probably want to cache results in memory (because disk read/write is slow too). If you are calling a function with the same arguments, only the first call since the last start of the Python interpreter will be slower. All subsequent calls will access the cache (if your cache is large enough to store all results).

Wtih Python >=3.2 there is even a built-in decorator [`@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=100, typed=False)`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

> Decorator to wrap a function with a memoizing callable that saves up to the maxsize most recent calls. It can save time when an expensive or I/O bound function is periodically called with the same arguments.

Example:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def get_pep(num):
    'Retrieve text of a Python Enhancement Proposal'
    resource = 'http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-%04d/' % num
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(resource) as s:
            return s.read()
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        return 'Not Found'

>>> for n in 8, 290, 308, 320, 8, 218, 320, 279, 289, 320, 9991:
...     pep = get_pep(n)
...     print(n, len(pep))

>>> get_pep.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=3, misses=8, maxsize=32, currsize=8)
```

There is a [backport for Python 2.7 on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.functools_lru_cache/1.0.1) and the [cachetools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cachetools/1.0.0) package, which is also Python 2.7 compatible and contains also variants of the Python 3 @functools.lru_cache function decorator.

### Persistent data on disk

If you want to keep data after the Python process has finished, it makes sense to store the data on disk. This might speed up also the first function call, but it might slow down all other function calls because it needs to read and write to the file.

@rrauenza's solutions looks good. With some small improvements:

```
import pickle
import functools
import collections
# or import cPickle as pickle

def persist_cache_to_disk(filename):
    def decorator(original_func):
        try:
            cache = pickle.load(open(filename, 'r'))
        except (IOError, ValueError):
            cache = {}

        def save_data():
            pickle.dump(cache, open(filename, "w"))

        @functools.wraps(original_func)
        def new_func(*args):
            try:
                try:
                    hash(args)
                except TypeError:
                    # do not use cache because we cannot hash args
                    return original_func(*args)

                if tuple(args) not in cache:
                    cache[tuple(args)] = original_func(*args)
                    # dump complete cache,  this can be expensive!
                    save_data()
                return cache[args]
        return new_func

    return decorator
```

Function calls are also cached in memory here similar to @functools.lru_cache(), but it does not implement a maximum cache size (potential problem for memory usage of the programm) nor something similar to the `typed` option (see above).

Unfortunately [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) (as suggested by @Aya) cannot be used directly, because only strings are supported as keys. This should bring better performance, because it does not need to write the complete cache on every update.

Pickle is not the preferred way to go if the use case is not a cache, but rather a storage of data between Python interpreter starts. Pickled files become useless, if you have to change the classes of the pickled objects. A cache can be cleared in such a case, but in other cases think about using yml, json or xml or if you have large data some binary format (e.g. hdf5).

### Pitfalls

1. Not all arguments hashable

All arguments must be hashable. For example lists and dictionaries are not hashable. There is no easy and general solution for this. Think carefully what kind of parameters you need to support. Lists can be converted to tuples easily. Also for dictionaries can be made hashable. Unfortunately this applies to all caching methods above (including the built-in @functools.lru_cache).

2. Not all return values pickle-able

Data needs to be serialized to be stored on disk. This is done often by using the [pickle](https://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module. Also [shelve](https://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) uses pickle internally. Unfortunately [not every object can be pickled](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). If the functions contain non pickable-able objects, you can try to make them pickle-able or choose a different way to serialize data (and a different file format to store the serialized data). If you use numpy objects [numnpy.save()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) is a very fast way to store large arrays of data.

3. Loss of type information

Objects might be equal, but not of same type. If your function depends also on the type of the input arguments, you might run into troubles:

```
@functools.lru_cache(typed=False)
def fun_with_numbers(a, b):
    return a/b, isinstance(3, float)
```

The [division fails only with Python 2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/):

```
>>> fun_with_numbers(1, 3)
0, False
>>> fun_with_numbers(1., 3.)
0, False
```

With @functools.lru_cache() you can solve this issue by setting `typed=True`, but if you use a different caching method you might need to implement something similar on your own.

4. Function does not depend only on input arguments

For obvious reasons the function should not depend on non-constant global variables or other external parameters. If the function returns `time.time()`, it will always return the cached time from the first function call.

5. Thread-safety

Really bad things can happen if you use cached functions at the same time without proper locking.

6. Do you really need it?

You should do [profiling](https://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) before and after adding caching. Caching might slow down your code if it was fast before.

Comment: `Hashable` is `True` for `([1],)` while `hash` is not.

Comment: You should use `str(args)` as the key.

Comment: @NizamMohamed Uh true, thanks for pointing that out! I corrected my answer. Using str(args) as key seems to be quite dangerous as general approach. If you know the input arguments, you could do that of course.